# Sort linked list in place

Tags: sorting, linked-list, selection-sort

I have a struct type node:

```c
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

I have a linked list using this node structure. I can sort this linked list using another linked list and copying node values there, but I want to implement a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) in the linked list. I have gone through some questions and articles but it is not clear to me whether this is possible. Do I need an index to implement selection sort? If it is possible then how can I proceed?

Comment: `any suggestion?` Yeah, write some sorting code. Seriously. What is your question? You just want someone to give you the code?

Comment: lmao, please do my homework SO ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection sort is meant for arrays, vectors, things that have random access iterators and no links like next pointers, (the links create an overhead when swapping elements). For a simple list sort, start with an empty list that will become the sorted list, say this is struct node *sorted = NULL; . Remove nodes one at at time from the original list and insert them into the sorted list (that starts off as an empty list) in sorted order.

Write some code and update your answer with what you've tried so far.

Comment: so i can not implement selection sort in a linked list?

Comment: @avijitbhattacharjee - Selection sort with a list is a bit more complicated. Start with a scan pointer set to start at the first node of a list. Scan the list for the "smallest" node, then swap that node with the first node of the list (if different), then advance the scan pointer to the second node, and repeat until you go through the list. To swap nodes, swap whatever is pointing to those two nodes, then swap those two nodes next pointers (in that order).